# Javascript Scope (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Ajax Call, in an OnClick event.

Inside the OnClick, I set a `var type = $(this).closest("table").attr("id");`

I am trying to call this `type` inside the Ajax's complete function().

But it shows as undefined.

Maybe someone can explain a lil bit why this is happening?

Thanks!!

```
$(document).on('click','.swaction',function(event){
    var pdfId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
    var type = $(this).closest("table").attr("id");
    event.preventDefault();

    if( $(this).data('action') === 'delete' )
    {
      var currentElement = this;
      if( confirm( "¿Está seguro de querer eliminar el \nPDF Nº " + pdfId + '?' ) )
      {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'ct_form_procesar_escaneos/pdf/delete/'+ type + '/' + pdfId,
          method: 'POST',
          error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
          {
            alert( errorThrown );
          },
          complete: function()
          {
            var a = type; // undefined
            $(currentElement).closest('tr').fadeOut(600, function(){
              $(currentElement).remove();
              $.procesar_escaneos.removeOnEmpty( type );
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if the type is defined after your initialization?

Comment: Yes, because the URL works good having `type`

Comment: Scope seems ok. have you tried using a different variable name? maybe this one is overwritten somehow on a different scope.

Comment: Yep, you're gonna have trouble doing this.  Especially with jQuery you run into weird hoisting issues.  [Check out this article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) and see if it helps you.

Comment: I modified your code a bit so it could run in console, and set a string value to type, and had no problem retrieving it after the 'complete' callback, meaning scope is ok. I would check again if type really has a value. Is there any chance the value is the object you are removing?

Comment: I made a simple test based on your code with jsfiddle, and it appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/aHA5a/1/, at least on my browser. Can you check on your side ?

Comment: Thanks for the examples, I see there's no problem there. I will re look more carefully at the code tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, the `this` keyword takes it's context dynamically depending of the function it is called from. When you call `type` from within an Ajax callback, the context has changed and `this` is not the same object.

Since javascript uses lexical scoping, you can save a reference to the `this` object when the context is right and then use this reference in your function.

```
var self = this;
var type = $(self).closest("table").attr("id");
```

This will work.